# How to get the recipient ID on Facebook API v2.4 and newer (RestFB/Facebook4J)

Tags: java, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to send messages to customers who want to know the current state of their order. Now I know that you can only send messages to someone who sent you a message because you need to have the specific recipient ID. The problem with this is that if I want to get the recipient ID I need to read my mailbox and therefore need the permission: read_mailbox. But read_mailbox is deprecated as of Facebook API v2.4 and newer. I don't think that it is impossible to do it though. Question beeing, how to do it with v2.4 or newer?

**Edit:** Thanks CBroe for the answer
Last problem now is that when I get a specific message it only gives me the created_time and the id back. Same thing when I try it with the GraphAPI Explorer

This:

```
JsonObject message = getFacebookClient().fetchObject("m_mid.1467893842385:ae7475981839704062", JsonObject.class);
```

Gives this:

```
{
  "created_time": "2016-07-07T12:17:22+0000",
  "id": "m_mid.1467893842385:ae7475981839704062"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing a parameter or a permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this doesn’t need `read_mailbox` permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations#read:

> A *page access token* with `read_page_mailboxes` permission is required.

So you have to ask for that permission, plus `manage_pages` of course (because you need the latter to get a page access token.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried around a little bit and I just had to create a page, use the page access token and fetch with "{page-id}/conversations"